# disable a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a round rect `UIButton` with an action method defined to it `-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender`. Now I wanna create another method `-(void)disableButton` which disables this button of mine. So I can call this function whenever I need. How can I use this `mybtn.enabled = NO;` into this function? What will this function look like?

Comment: `-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender{ [self disableButton ];}  -(void)disableButton { mybtn.enabled = NO; }`

Comment: if you want to disable on click than why not disable in click only like cast as UIButton *yourButton =(UIButton*)sender and than yourButton.enabled= NO or yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: You need to call mybtn.enabled = NO; from a C function or from a method ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple solution

I assume **mybtn** will be in your header file as a instance variable

Take another button and bind this below IBAction or you can call this function directly in the same class like this `[self disableButton];`

```
-(IBAction)disableButton {
   //Disable  mybtn
    mybtn.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using IB for button then create an IBOutlet for your button and map it with the button in InterfaceBuilder.

```
IBOutlet UIBUTTON *mybtn;
```

Now in :

```
-(void)disableButton{

mybtn.enabled = NO;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

.h

```
 {
 IBOutlet UIBUTTON *mybtn;
 }
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender;
-(void)disableButton;
```

.m

```
 -(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender{ 
  [self disableButton];
  }
   -(void)disableButton {
    mybtn.enabled = NO;
  }
```